Решить задачу на python,оптимизировать
n = int(input())
total_sum = n * (n + 1) // 2
count = 0

# Перебираем все возможные позиции начала и конца.
for i in range(1, n + 1):
   for j in range(i, n + 1):
    removed_sum = (j * (j + 1)) // 2 - ((i - 1) * i) // 2
    
    if total_sum - removed_sum == removed_sum:
        count += 1

print(count)


Задача E. Erasing numbers
Входной файл: Стандартный вход
Ограничение времени: 1 сек
Выходной файл: Стандартный выход
Ограничение памяти: 256 Мб
Условие
В Научно-исследовательском институте, где работает Тимофей, продолжается успешное исследование
ряда натуральных чисел. Каждый день его коллеги открывают всё новые и новые свойства этой
последовательности, и Тимофей старается от них не отставать. Сегодня Тимофей, как обычно, выписал
на доске в ряд натуральные числа от 1 до и пытается ответить на вопрос, возможно ли стереть в
середине списка несколько (не менее одного) чисел, идущих подряд, чтобы сумма оставшихся чисел
слева равнялась сумме оставшихся чисел справа?
Формат входных данных
Единственная строка входных данных содержит натуральное число .
Формат выходных данных
Выведите в первой строке неотрицательное целое число — количество различных способов стереть
числа.
Ограничения
3 ≤ n ≤ 10^5
Пояснения к примерам.
В первом примере дано . Перечислим все способы стереть числа в середине ряда:
1 # 3 4 5
1 2 # 4 5
1 2 3 # 5
1 # # 4 5
1 2 # # 5
1 # # # 5

Ни в одном из них нужное свойство не достигается.
Во втором примере дано . Перечислим все хорошие способы стереть числа в середине ряда:
1 2 3 4 5 6 # # # ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## 21
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ## ## ## ## ## 18 19 20 21

В первом списке сумма чисел слева и справа равны 21, во втором — 78. Всего два способа.

Где ваши попытки решения? Задача не слишком сложная, надо хоть что-то попробовать сделать.

надо написать код на  python.

@ASSA Принципы этого форума такие, что учебные задачи тут за вас не делают. Вам помогают понять, как их сделать. Если учебные задачи делать за вас, то вы ничему не научитесь, это плохо.

а почему -3 голоса?

@ASSA Минусуют по тому же принципу: вы даже не начали писать код, а только привели в вопросе задание и всё.

Код добавляйте в вопрос текстом, так с ним удобнее работать. И таковы правила.

написал. правильно?

Да, теперь лучше. Минусы не от меня, я вам плюс за старание улучшить вопрос поставил

этот код работает?

этот код работает? А вы не проверяли? Судя по отсутствию знаков умножения - нет...

@ASSA Он синтаксически некорректен, считает за O(n^2) и делает лишние вычисления сущностей. Но для начала уже хорошо.

Тут явно напрашивается одна из типовых методик для решения алгоритмических задач - "метод двух указателей".

Делаем два указателя - на начало списка и на конец списка
Идём по условиям (см. ниже) с начала списка вперёд первым указателем и с конца к началу вторым указателем
Попутно аккумулируем две суммы - от начала списка до первого указателя и от второго указателя до конца списка
В зависимости от того, равны суммы или какая-то из них больше, либо увеличиваем список найденных вариантов, либо сдвигаем тот указатель, чья сумма меньше
Когда указатели встретятся, выводим результат

Сложность получается O(n), по идее этого вполне достаточно. Но в дальнейшем я бы проверил, может левый указатель нужно сдвигать не по одной позиции, а воспользоваться двоичным поиском, для больших последовательностей это должно даль дополнительную оптимизацию.
Можно вспомнить ещё формулы для суммы чисел ряда, возможно они тоже дадут какую-то оптимизацию, но это нужно ещё подумать. Возможно, это позволит сдвигать левый указатель сразу на вычисленную позицию, пересчитав её из разницы сумм и текущего числа под левым указателем.
Код сами напишите, он совсем не сложный, тут главное алгоритм придумать.

Двоичный поиск не нужен. Шаг на левом краю вычисляется аналитически "за один корень". В целом это даст сложность N^0.5. Очень не плохо.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Да, по идее видимо нужно будет из формулы суммы ряда сделать формулу, говорящую, есть ли целое число чисел ряда, которое может дать нужную сумму ряда. Ну и когда идём справа налево проверять каждый раз по этой формуле, пока искомое число чисел ряда из этой формулы меньше правого указателя.

Я глупость написал. Там правый указатель делает O(N) шагов до "середины". Так что аналитическое вычисление шага только улучшит константу.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Да, но суммарная середина же будет не посередине ряда, а смещённая вправо. Вопрос в том - какова зависимость этого смещения от N. Может там и корень, но считать у меня голова пухнет. )

N - N/(2**0.5)
